# Matrix form of least squares fitting

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares, pseudoinverse

I need to fit some 3D $\left(x_{i},y_{i},z_{i}\right)$ data to a spherical surface.  I tried doing this:

Assuming that not all points are coplanar, one has to minimize the function:

\begin{equation}
F\left(a,b,c,r\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(r_{i}-r\right)^2,
\label{spherefunctional}
\end{equation}
where $r$ is the sphere radius and

\begin{equation}
r_{i}=\sqrt{\left(x_{i}-a\right)^2+\left(y_{i}-b\right)^2+\left(z_{i}-c\right)}    
\label{defri}
\end{equation}

Taking the partial derivative of $F$ with respect to $r$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(r_{i}-r\right)
\end{equation}
and making it equal to zero:
\begin{equation}
r=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}r_{i}
\end{equation}

Similarly, taking the other partial derivatives and making them equal to zero:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}+\frac{r}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial a}\\
b&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y_{i}+\frac{r}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial b}\\
c&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}z_{i}+\frac{r}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial c}
\end{split}
\end{align}

Since:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial a}&=\frac{\left(a-x_{i}\right)}{r_{i}}\\
\frac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial b}&=\frac{\left(b-y_{i}\right)}{r_{i}}\\
\frac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial c}&=\frac{\left(c-z_{i}\right)}{r_{i}}
\end{split}
\end{align}

Then:

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}+\frac{1}{m^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{m}r_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\left(a-x_{i}\right)}{r_{i}}\\
b&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y_{i}+\frac{1}{m^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{m}r_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\left(b-y_{i}\right)}{r_{i}}\\
c&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}z_{i}+\frac{1}{m^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{m}r_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\left(c-z_{i}\right)}{r_{i}}
\end{split}
\end{align}

However, solving the previous equations is cumbersome. So I did some more research and found this [report](http://www.janssenprecisionengineering.com/downloads/Fit-sphere-through-points.pdf), which shows how to fit some data solving linear equations like so:

\begin{align}
Ax &= B\\
A^TA\hat{x} &= A^TB\\
\hat{x} &= (A^TA)^{-1}A^TB
\end{align}

Where $A$ and $B$ are shown in the report. That approach is much simpler and yields good results. However, I can't derive the expressions for those matrices. Are they compatible with the optimization function?

Comment: It doesn´t seem that your objective function has a minimum. I´ve made a calculation with two variables and three data points, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+%28%28%281-a%29%5E2%2B%282-b%29%5E2%29%5E0.5-6%29%5E2%2B%28%28%282-a%29%5E2%2B%285-b%29%5E2%29%5E0.5-30%29%5E2%2B%28%28%283-a%29%5E2%2B%286-b%29%5E2%29%5E0.5-9%29%5E2)

Comment: It does. I can solve the system numerically, but I am looking for analytical solutions that don't depend on $r_{i}$, like the one shown in the report.

Comment: Then why my calculation hasn´t worked?

Comment: Your calculation is different. I want to minimize the distances between the best sphere fit and some data. That function has a minimum.